# USB to Serial Connection - Danger to Motherboard from Electric Shock?

Tags: usb, motherboard, serial-port, rs232, surge-protection

Last night I setup a machine that talks to our security system over Serial Connection. The serial cable goes through the roof of our building. The machine I setup this one, also hosts important VM's. A co-worker said he thinks this is extremley dangerous as the serial cable could fry the mother board if it got a power surge.

Does this fear have merit? He recommended getting Serial to Ethernet adapter (100/150$), then either connecting to switch, or an AP, then getting another AP with a Ethernet to serial connection.

What are your thoughts, is this overboard?

There is also this device, but his words, 15$ device protecting 3K Server, which I understand.

[https://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-DB9-Connection-Protector/dp/B00006B81G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006B81G)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up getting this Optical Isolated serial to USB adapter, which should protect from a surge.

```
Circuit isolation provides electrical protection for sensitive, and often expensive industrial equipment
```

[https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Adapter-Optical-Isolation-ICUSB2321FIS/dp/B006DJ5FI4/ref=sr_1_2?s=aht&ie=UTF8&qid=1483338218&sr=8-2&keywords=Serial+to+USB+isolated](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006DJ5FI4)